# Why is Natsuno shown with a turtle in some fan arts?

Tags: shiki

Some fan arts of *Shiki* depict Natsuno with a turtle:

- https://www.zerochan.net/1136297
- https://www.zerochan.net/808391 (turtle reflection in the glass of wine)
- https://www.zerochan.net/363691

Also, Natsuno's father is shown with a dead turtle in other fan arts.

I've only watched the anime and I'm really curious.

Is there any explanation for this, something in the manga or novel?

Comment: Natsuno's father has cooked him a turtle soup at some point. It might have something to do with that. But I am not sure about the significance of the turtle (soup).